# Convergence of a sequence of number.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, discrete-mathematics

Let $0<\varepsilon<1$ be a very small number. Define a sequence of number by
$$
a_1=1+\varepsilon,\,\, a_2=1+\varepsilon a_1^2,\,\, a_3=1+\varepsilon a_2^2,\,\,\cdots,\,\, a_n=1+\varepsilon a_{n-1}^2,\cdots
$$
Under what condition on $\varepsilon$, does the limit of $a_n$ exists, i.e.,
$$
a=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n<\infty?
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $C_n$ be the $n^{\text{th}}$ [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).  Notice 
$$  a_1 = C_0 + C_1 \varepsilon \text{.}  $$
By a tedious induction (that I have no plan to type up here, which uses the [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Properties) to simplify the squares of the sums)
$$  a_n = \left( \sum_{k=0}^n C_k \varepsilon^k \right) + \text{higher powers of $\varepsilon$}  \text{.}  $$
The generating function of the Catalan numbers (q.v. ["the first proof"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof)) is 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty C_k \varepsilon^k = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\varepsilon}}{2\varepsilon}  $$
The sequence of $a_i$ are clearly real-valued, so we must have $0 < \varepsilon \leq \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Many thanks for your help!